# How to get gps Location with an iPod Touch (4th gen)

Tags: ios, iphone, gps, location, core-location

I guess the answer has already been posted, but I am a lazzy boy :p .

Seriously I am working on an iPhone Application which have to blit a map
and use the current user gps location to locate the user on the map.

The problem is that with iPhone (v1), and all iPod version there is no gps device,
so is it possible to get the current gps location of the user (using google map api, with internet ... or something else) ?
I would like to know the current gps user location without user gps device since there is no such device in iPhone v1 and iPod Touch :-) .

Thanks a lot for your advices.

Comment: It works roughly in the WiFi-only iPad, which does not have GPS. Have you tried calling the normal services to see if they work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean to get the current location? As you said, the iPod touch has no GPS, so you won't be able to get a GPS location.

If you mean just "location", then yes, Core Location does what you want (by using Wi-Fi triangulation). Check out the documentation of [CLLocationManager](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/).

Comment: Hmm so what's the real difference with the return value of GPS and the return value of the Core Location ? (is it possible to get lambert 2 location using Core Location for example ?), thanks.

Comment: You always go through Core Location. There's no way to talk to the GPS directly. Just the accuracy of the returned location updates is different depending on the features of the device.

Comment: Ok, so GPS or not , if I have a internet connection I will get the user location, but without GPS the location is not really precise, that's right ?

Comment: Right. Provided of course, the Wi-Fi network is listed in Apple's database. Normally this is the case, though. Wi-Fi positioning is rather precise actually, 50-100 m.

Comment: Ok , you rock dude :-) .
Thank you a lot.