# IPod Touch CLLocation Tracking Limitations?

Tags: iphone, ios, geolocation, ipod-touch

Im just wondering whether anyone knows if there is any limitations of the ipod touch when it comes to location tracking of the device? Can you get the long/lat and altitude of the device?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The iPod touch doesn't have GPS or cell tower location capability, so yes, there are limitations.

It will acquire Lat / Lon from any nearby Wifi points but will not have any altitude info.

See also;

[How to get gps Location with an iPod Touch (4th gen)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4166378/how-to-get-gps-location-with-an-ipod-touch-4th-gen)